# Placement of context menu on devex grid control

Tags: wpf

I am using a devexpress grid control to display a grid. The grid shows a context menu. When i right click on a row, the menu is shown but only when the row is a newly added row. It means the menu is visible only on some rows so i have bound its visibility with a property on view model. The problem is if i right click on a row which doesn't show a context menu and then right click on the row which shows the context menu, the menu becomes visible on the last clicked row(the one which doesn't show context). Any help with this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: <dxg:GridControl Name="gridTest" SelectionMode="Cell" CurrentItemChanged="gridTest_CurrentItemChanged"              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyElements}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Element,Mode=TwoWay}">
<dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>
 <ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding IsContextMenuVisible}">
        <MenuItem Header="Delete Row" Command="{Binding DeleteRowCommand}"/>
       </ContextMenu>
      </dxg:GridControl.ContextMenu>  
Code Behind
private void gridTest_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e){ if (e.NewItem != null) { SelectedItem = e.NewItem; } }